# Is it possible to nest CASE-statement into WHERE clause?

Tags: oracle, query, case, where

I am developing an application with FastAPI. It contains a function that brings two variables into a SQL query using the `sqlalchemy.sql.text` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268050/execute-sql-from-file-in-sqlalchemy/63442962#63442962).

```sql
SELECT ATTR3
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTR1 = TO_NUMBER(:var1)
  AND (CASE
          WHEN TO_NUMBER(:var1) NOT IN (1460, 1478, 1481) THEN 'ATTR2 IS NULL'
          ELSE ATTR2 = TO_NUMBER(:var2)
      END);
```

So, after pasting the variables, the SQL query will look as following

```sql
SELECT ATTR3
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTR1 = TO_NUMBER('1460')
  AND (CASE
           WHEN TO_NUMBER('1460') NOT IN (1460, 1478, 1481) THEN 'ATTR2 IS NULL'
           ELSE ATTR2 = TO_NUMBER('000')
       END);
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

So, now I am wondering how can I resolve this issue? As well as if it is possible to nest a CASE-statement into the WHERE clause?

Here is the logic of m SQL statements:

[image: logic]

I have seen some related topics, but they were not helpful.

- [“CASE” statement within “WHERE” clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)
- [Nested case statements vs multiple criteria case statements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239583/nested-case-statements-vs-multiple-criteria-case-statements)
- [Case statement in WHERE clause in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255800/case-statement-in-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, so this is a wild guess:

```
SELECT ATTR3
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTR1 = TO_NUMBER(:var1)
  AND ((TO_NUMBER(:var1) NOT IN (1460, 1478, 1481) AND ATTR2 IS NULL)
       OR
       (TO_NUMBER(:var1) IN (1460, 1478, 1481) AND ATTR2 = TO_NUMBER(:var2))
       ;
```

I added some redundant parentheses for clarity. Using a union is another possibility:

```
SELECT ATTR3
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTR1 = TO_NUMBER(:var1)
  AND TO_NUMBER(:var1) NOT IN (1460, 1478, 1481) 
  AND ATTR2 IS NULL
UNION
SELECT ATTR3
FROM TABLE
WHERE ATTR1 = TO_NUMBER(:var1)
  AND TO_NUMBER(:var1) IN (1460, 1478, 1481) 
  AND ATTR2 = TO_NUMBER(:var2)
```

Add a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar to your post, together with the expected output if this did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you can avoid to use CASE, just use AND, OR.

Given the next example:

```
create table t (atr1 int, atr2 int);
insert into t values
(1, 15),(2, 30),(3, 45),(1, 30),(2, null),(3, 90);

declare @var1 int = 2;
declare @var2 int = 30;
```

You could write your query as:

```
select
    *
from
    t
where
    atr1 = @var1
    and
    (
      (@var2 not in (3, 4) and atr2 is null)
      or
      (@var2 in (3, 4) and atr2 = @var2)
    );
```

> ```
> atr1 | atr2
> ---: | ---:
>    2 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00cb5474e11f5e4b6c62035370c999e0)*